# printContent is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, java, html, function

I keep getting this error

```
printContent is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

This is my function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function printContent(){
str=document.getElementById('form').innerHTML
newwin=window.open('','printwin','left=100,top=100,width=900,height=550')
newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Entry Slip</TITLE>\n')
newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('else{\n')
newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000000)\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')
newwin.document.write(str)
newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
newwin.document.close()
}
//-->
</script>
```

and this is my input code

```
<input type="submit" value="Print" onclick="printContent()">
```

my code works fine on a localhost, but when I try to upload it on a webhost the print function does not work anymore.

Comment: first I doubt you want a submit button since you are not submitting a form.

Comment: I'm also trying to submit a form at the same time.